# Can we simplify this factorial summation $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i!(n-i)!$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I've just solved a combinatorics problem  but my answer is stuck here:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i!(n-i)!$$
Is there any way to simplify this summation? I've thought about combinatorial proof but there's no hope. Thank you:).

Comment: the formula for this sum looks complegated

Comment: We are essentially looking at the sum of the reciprocals of the binomial coefficients. I think I recall there are nice identities but no known closed form.

Comment: what do you need it for? it smells a bit like a summand of the cauchy product of a series with itself...

Comment: https://oeis.org/A059371